# Can I define an equivalent to this using the Axiom command?

Tags: coq

`mu` can not be defined.

```
Definiton mu (A : Type) (f : A -> A) : A := f (mu A f).
```

However, the Axiom command can be used to pseudo-define `mu`.

```
Axiom mu : forall A : Type, (A -> A) -> A.

Axiom mu_beta : forall (A : Type) (f : A -> A), mu A f = f (mu A f).
```

Can I do the same for `higher_path` and `higher_path_argument`? Even after using several techniques, it still seems to be impossible.

```
Definition higher_path
  : forall n : nat, higher_path_argument n -> Type
  := fun n : nat =>
    match n with
    | O => fun x : higher_path_argument 0 => x
    | S n_p =>
      fun x : higher_path_argument (S n_p) =>
        match x with
        | existT _ x_a x_b =>
          match x_b with
          | pair x_b_a x_b_b => x_b_a = x_b_b :> higher_path n_p x_a
          end
        end
    end.

Definition higher_path_argument
  : nat -> Type
  := fun n : nat =>
    match n with
    | O => Type
    | S n_p =>
      sigT
        (A := higher_path_argument n_p)
        (fun x_p => prod (higher_path n_p x_p) (higher_path n_p x_p))
    end.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to start with

```
Axiom higher_path_argument : nat -> Type.
Axiom higher_path : forall n : nat, higher_path_argument n -> Type.
```

then `higher_path_argument_beta` which you will have to use in the `higher_path_beta` to *compute* the type. You will however end up with something really verbose however.

Comment: This answer feels incomplete.  Where does `higher_path_beta` come from?

Comment: I propose a high-level methodology. `higher_path_beta` will correspond to an equality stating the "definition" of `higher_path` but it seems really painful to write.

Comment: I already have [an implementation](https://github.com/Hexirp/googology-in-coq/blob/93a511ae6b9bbadd4474308fb7ceb67325950dd4/libraries/theories/Base.v#L750-L824) based on this idea.